# pyramid_layout and configure.zcml

Tags: pyramid

I'm trying to use pyramid_layout package for declarative configuration of my app. I would like to configure it only in configure.zcml file.

Here it is:

```
<configure xmlns="http://pylonshq.com/pyramid"
       xmlns:lat="http://pylonshq.com/pyramid_layout">

    <include package="pyramid_zcml" />
    <include package="pyramid_layout" file="meta.zcml"/>

    <static
        name="static"
        path="static"
    />

    <!-- layouts -->
    <lat:layout
        name="test"
        layout=".layouts.AppLayout"
        template="templates/layouts/layout1.pt"
    />

    <!-- default view -->
    <view
        view=".views.my_view"
        renderer="templates/home.pt"
        lat:layout="test"
    />

    <view
        name="two"
        view=".views.my_view2"
        renderer="templates/mytemplate2.pt"
    />

</configure>
```

When I called the default view - got an exception:

```
NameError: main_template

 - Expression: "main_template"
 - Filename:   ... o\python_test\pyramid7\myzcml1\myzcml1\templates\home.pt
 - Location:   (line 4: col 25)
 - Source:     <metal:block use-macro="main_template">
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 - Arguments:  repeat: {...} (0)
               renderer_name: templates/home.pt
               req: <Request - at 0x4a96be0L>
               request: <Request - at 0x4a96be0L>
```

File home.pt:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal" >
    <metal:block use-macro="main_template">
        <div metal:fill-slot="content">
            <h1>It is home view</h1>
            <p>Hello home.pt template</p>
            <p>Project is: ${project}</p>
        </div>
    </metal:block>
</html>
```

BTW, if I use request.layout_manager.use_layout("test") in view.my_view code - it works fine!

What I did wrong in my code? So, is it possible to use pyramid_layout in such manner? Is it possible?

Comment: Where does `main_template` macro come from? It supposed to be either a macro defined in the same file (via metal:define-macro) or a Chameleon template instance. See http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#macros-metal for details

Comment: As I understand http://pyramid-layout.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html, `main_template` is available to all templates